# Not able to take input using using gets( ) function

Tags: c, scanf, gets

**Q.1)Write a program to display user details as User name,Email,Contact no,Address each on new line.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main(){

char username[25],Email[40],contact[15],add[80];
clrscr();//to be used after   
printf("Enter all your details below\n");


*//gets() function does not work after the scanf() function.
//i.e  gets() should be written on top after declaration to work.*

printf("username :");
scanf("%s",&username[0]);

printf("Enter your Address:");
gets(add);        // **←---------------------------------------GETS( ) inserted after scanf()**

printf("Email ID :");
scanf("%s",Email);

printf("Contact :");
scanf("%s",contact);

printf("\nYour username is %s\n",username);
printf("Your Email ID is %s\n",Email);
printf("Your Contact No. is %s\n",contact);
printf("Your Address is %s\n",add);

getch();
}
```

**gets() function is not taking any input from the user; once it is used after scanf() function.**

1.I don't know why gets function is behaving in this manner??
**2**.Same happens with **scanf("%c")***[format specifier for char]* when its is used after **scanf("%s")***[format specifier of string]*

Comment: You also really want to read [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. dont use `void main()` C++ has never permitted void main(), though some compilers might permit it either as an extension or just because they don't diagnose it.

Similarly C has never permitted `void main()` other than as an extension; the same 1989 standard that introduced the void keyword.There is no particular advantage in being able to write `void main()` rather than `int main()`. You don't even need to explicitly return a value; falling off the end of main is equivalent to return 0; (in C++, and in C starting with C99).

2. `gets()`The basic problem is that the function doesn't know how big the buffer is, so it continues reading until it finds a newline or encounters EOF, and may overflow the bounds of the buffer it was given.so,use `scanf("%[^\n]s", name);` instead of `gets(name);`.
3. `<conio.h>` is a C header file used mostly by MS-DOS compilers to provide console input/output. It is not part of the C standard library or ISO C, nor is it defined by POSIX.so, try use some other compilers.

here is the working version

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

 char username[25],Email[40],contact[15],add[80];
//to be used after   
printf("Enter all your details below\n");


//gets() function does not work after the scanf() function.
//i.e  gets() should be written on top after declaration to work.*

printf("username :");
scanf("%[^\r\n]s",username);
getchar();
printf("Enter your Address:");
scanf("%[^\n]s", add);        

printf("Email ID :");
scanf("%s",Email);

printf("Contact :");
scanf("%s",contact);

printf("\nYour username is '%s'\n",username);
printf("Your Email ID is '%s'\n",Email);
printf("Your Contact No. is '%s'\n",contact);
printf("Your Address is '%s'\n",add);

return 0;
}
```

the address is taking  a newline character from the username statement.so, to print the address properly i used the `getchar()` function,which detected the newline character before the address taken the input.

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s", name);` is no safer than `gets` since you did not specify a maximum length.